# In Cognos 8 Report/Event Studio: need to subtract from a date

Tags: cognos

How do I calculate a subtract function from a date field using the functions in Cognos 8 Report/Event studio?

I have credential expiration dates and I need to set an alert in Event Studio to let managers know when someone's credentials are 90 days from expiring.  Some dates are in 2012,2013,and 2014.

I can't seem to make the system tools subtract on dates.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is actual date field you can use the following expression:

```
_add_days ([Date],-90)
```

Here how its looks like in Report Studio:[image]

And the results: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[Credential Exp Date] - current_date <= 90**

(REQUIRED: the credential exp date is a DATE field, or else you will need to convert that into a date using something like to_date(...) )

Answer (score 0):

I think Ran's way should be the right way unless you want to use this function: `_add_months`

```
 _add_months ([Date],-3)
```